# Can This Expression Be Simplified? (Involves Square Roots)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals

I started with the expression

$$
\frac{4mlt(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}})c^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

and have ended up at:

$$
\frac{4mlt(c^2 - c \sqrt{c^2-v^2})}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

Is it possible to further simplify this (second) expression?

Btw it is about the change in the spacetime variables shifting, as defined by the special relativity.

Comment: Not really no. Although the terms $\beta = v/c$ and $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} = 1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ are so commonly used in S.R., that you might want to use $\beta$ or $\gamma$ as abbreviations in your expression. E.g.,

$$\frac{4mltc^2(1-1/\gamma)}{1/\gamma} = 4mltc^2(\gamma - 1)$$

Comment: Just a little comment: remember that $v\leq c$ (in the second expression you write $\sqrt{v^2-c^2}$)

Comment: Eh. Yes you are right. My bad. I should edit it. It was supposed to be c² - v²

Comment: That was very helpful @ Simon S. You should have posted it as an answer :)